# Не нормально срабатывает скрипт в AHK

Tags: клавиатура, hotkeys, autohotkey

Доброго дня !

Есть скрипт для AutoHotKey:

```
!F8::
{
    Send, {Ctrl Down}{x}{Ctrl Up}{UP}{right}{Ctrl Down}{v}{Ctrl Up}{left}{down}{down}{down}
}
Return
```

1. В большинстве случаев работает, как надо - при нажатии alt+F8 вырезает содержимое ячейки в экселе и кладет в ячейку выше-справа, НО!
2. Иногда действие клавиши CTRL "отваливается" и я вижу в ячейках символы "с" и "v"
3. После нескольких нажиманий разных клавиш, перезагрузок скрипта, либо вообще экселя или компа скрипт опять работает нормально.

4 .Я не понимаю, от чего это зависит.

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался. Спасибо!

Comment: Елки-палки .. я нашел замену CTRL+X и CTRL+V.
Send, ^{vk58}{UP}{right}^{vk56}{left}{down}{down}{down}.
Задача решена! Всем спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1):

AHK сложная штука и так вряд всё он не будет выполнять всегда идеально, и может получиться что он пойдет как бы асинхронно, не знаю как объснять в теории, но на практике часто такое было, лучше делать всё с таймаутами не большими чтобы наверняка:

```
!F8::
{
    Send ^{vk58}
    Sleep 50
    Send {up down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {up up}
    Sleep 50
    Send {right down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {right up}
    Sleep 50
    Send ^{vk56}
    Sleep 50
    Send {left down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {left up}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down up}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down up}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down up}
}
Return
```

Можно и без них обойтись, но иногда может не отрабатывать, код не тестировал, писал по аналогии со своими AHK скриптами, был бы Windows рядом проверил бы.

UPD. Хотя думаю вариант выше не совсем подойдет, может получиться что он будет клавишу зажимать и проскочит на пару ячеек курсор, попробуйте вот такой:

```
!F8::
{
    Send ^{vk58}
    Sleep 50
    Send {up}
    Sleep 50
    Send {right}
    Sleep 50
    Send ^{vk56}
    Sleep 50
    Send {left}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down}
    Sleep 50
    Send {down}
}
Return
```

Если 3-4 секунды для вас много попробуйте уменьшить значение `sleep`

Comment: Да, я вкурсе про непредсказуемость и таймауты, но все равно спасибо ! Но суть в том , что сейчас идет шикарно с новой конструкцией ;)

Comment: Send, ^{vk58}{UP}{right}^{vk56}{left}{down}{down}{down}